# Configure ejabberd with Mysql , Error p1_mysql.app not found

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I am trying to configure ejabberd with mysql database. After changes into the yml file i got this error while starting node.

```
2017-01-09 13:07:27.386 [critical] <0.38.0>@ejabberd:exit_or_halt:133 failed to start application 'p1_mysql': {error,
                                         {"no such file or directory",
                                          "p1_mysql.app"}}
```

Searching for solutions encountered with a step to hit './configure'

But i cannot locate the directory.

Tried it in /var/lib/ejabberd as well. says "not found"

Installed on Ubuntu using apt-get install ejabberd

How do i hit configure to do the needful.

Comment: One of easiest way would be to install from the ejabberd binary file. https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/

Comment: I had the same issue, but did not get an answer on SO. Hoping to find a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building from source, you should enable mysql support via configure script, e.g.

```
$ ./autogen.sh # Only needed if building directly from github repo
$ ./configure --enable-mysql
$ make
```